# Which of the following circles has the greatest number of points of intersection with the parabola $x^{2} = y + 4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, gre-exam

Which of the following circles has the greatest number of points of intersection with the parabola $x^2 = y + 4$?

(A) $x^2 + y^2=1$

(B) $x^2 + y^2=2$

(C) $x^2 + y^2=9$

(D) $x^2 + y^2=16$

(E) $x^2 + y^2=25$

I tried  to solve every equation by substituting the value of $x^2$ in it, but is this the smartest way to solve this question?

The question is supposed to be answered in no more than $2.5$ minutes

Comment: To any would-be answerers, note that the question is tagged [tag:gre-exam]. Presumably, during such an exam, one would not have access to a  graphing calculator, so simply graphing the various equation is probably not very helpful.

Comment: @pjs36 For equations like this, it is incredibly simple to plot them by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hopefully have noticed that all the given equations are circles centred at $(0,0)$ with radius $A=1$, $B=\sqrt2$, $C=3$, $D=4$, $E=5$.

We can quite easily plot the circles on a graph, and the initial parabola shouldn't provide many problems either:

[image: WolframAlpha graph]

*(graph from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%3Dy%2B4,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D2,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D9,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D16,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D25))*

From there, we can very quickly see which of the circles intersects with the parabola the most times

Comment: I think I would draw by hand in the GRE exam

Answer (score 2):

Hint: I think you may try plotting the graph. Not sure if the smartest way but you will clearly notice the vertex of parabola at (0,-4). Now try plotting the  equations and they may do the job.  (Constructive suggestion to the answer are welcome)

Comment: Plotting the last two equations won't help, because the answer is $C$

Comment: Saw that. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate $x$ between them leading to quadratic equation

$$ x^2+y^2= R^2,\, x^2= y+4 ,\, \rightarrow y^2+ y + 4- R^2 =0 $$

If its discriminant is $>0$ then real roots occur when

$$ R>\frac{\sqrt15} {2} \approx  1.9365$$

Repeated roots occur when $ R = \dfrac{\sqrt15}{2}  $

But graphically repeated roots occur also for

$$ R= 4 $$

EDIT 1:

For a comprehensive  algebraic ( analytical geometrical)  procedure (above is incomplete),

we next consider symmetry along y- axis, $x=0$

$$ y=-4, x=0, \rightarrow \, R=4 $$

which supplies another tangent point.

So the complete interval to be considered for maximum real roots cutting situation is:

$$ (\dfrac{\sqrt15}{2}<R  < 4 )$$

[image]

Comment: I do not understand your solution could u please provide more details? especially what do u mean by your last statement ?

Comment: Edited per your request. The upper limit of domain ( restricted ) $ R<4 $ could not be detected properly by the elementary criterion I gave ..

Comment: @ Smart and it is by symmetry $R=4$ is roped in.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to make completely algebraic what @Narasimhan's answer is saying is the following:

1. Follow what @Narasimhan said to get that $c > \sqrt{15}/2$ is needed for 2 distinct real roots.
2. Then, note that we want $x^2 = y+4$ AND $x^2 + y^2 = c^2$: in particular, let's extract information from the first desired equality as follows:

Now, if $y_0$ is such that $y_0 + 4 + y_0^2 - c^2 = 0$, then we know that $y_0 = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-15+4c^2}}{2}$. By the above, we require that $y_0 \geq -4$ (so that there is some real $x$ s.t. $x_0^2 = y_0+4$, i.e. we get a pair $(x_0,y_0)$ where circle and parabola intersect). But then, this means that $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-15+4c^2}}{2} \geq -4$.

This is satisfied if and only if $\frac{-1 - \sqrt{-15+4c^2}}{2} \geq -4$, but solving this gets us that $c^2 \leq 16$.

Finally, note that to get distinct pairs, we need $y_0 + 4 > 0$ (if not, then $x = 0$, but the parabola only has one point with x-coordinate 0). This imposes $c^2 < 16$.